# JQM navbar footer not bottom-aligned

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer, navbar

The example in http://jsfiddle.net/yotam/0w4wvmss/

```
<code>
$content.after(
$('<div>')
    .attr("data-role", "footer")
    .attr("data-position", "fixed")
    .append(
    $("<div>")
         .attr("data-role", "navbar")
         .append(ul)
    )
    .navbar()
);
</code>
```

has 4 JQM-pages, each with similar footer-navbar programmatically defined.
Each navbar has 3 buttons 'href'-ing the other pages.

As expected, all footers are bottom aligned as they should,
except that of the first page.

Why is the footer of the first page not aligned to the bottom?

Answer (score -1):

You need to reapply the JQM styles after creating the menu.
The below made your fiddle work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    xnavbar.init();
    $('#club').trigger("create");
});
```

Comment: With jQM 1.4.x you can also use $("#club").enhanceWithin(); (API DOC: http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/ )